# How Create array with uniq key using php

Tags: php, arrays

How Create Array like this.

```
array(34) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#11 (2) 
        { ["id"]=> string(2) "11" ["name"]=> string(4) "AAAAA" } 
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#12 (2) 
        { ["id"]=> string(2) "12" ["name"]=> string(14) "BBBBB" }
}
```

the array I get from database and i use for select option, but i wont create manualy in code how make the array like that.

this my code.

```
$OPT_name = array('id'=>'0','name'=>'-Pilih-','id'=>'AAAAA','name'=>'BBBBB')";
var_dump($OPT_name);
exit;
```

but can't like example in a above.

Comment: This can't work. You can't have duplicate keys in your array.

Comment: `$asd = array((object) array('id' => '1'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have there an array containing basic stdClass objects.

Use this:

```
$arr = array();

$o1 = new stdClass();
$o1->id = 1;
$o1->name = "ASD";

$o2 = new stdClass();
$o2->id = 2;
$o2->name = "name2";
// define as many $oN you need

$arr[] = $o1;
$arr[] = $o2;
// add them to the array
```

And that's it!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after..

If you're doing a:

```
SELECT id,name FROM <wherever>
```

Try:

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
  $obj = new StdClass();
  $obj->id = $row['id'];
  $obj->name = $row['name'];
  $array[] = $obj;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the method in your comment is terse and concise +1